# Concatenate two strings and get null if both are null

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation

I am looking for a solution to concatenate two string values and get `null` as a result if both are `null`.
None of `string1 + string2`, `string.Concat(string1, string2)`, `string.Join(string1, string2)` work. Research shows that is due to the fact, that these methods internally treat null as empty string.

How to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just check `string1 == null &&  string2 == null` beforehand?

Comment: `string result = string1 == null && string2 == null ? null : string1 + string2;`

Comment: If fact I aim for more complicated formula eventually: `(a + b) ?? (c + d)`, however `a + b` does not evaluate to `null` when both `a` and `b` are `null`

Comment: `string result = (a == null && b == null) ? c + d : a + b;` if both `a` and `b` are `null` we should compute `c + d`, otherwise `a + b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class StringTest
{
    public string CustomConcat(string one, string two) => 
        one == null && two == null 
            ? null 
            : string.Concat(one, two);

    [Test]
    public void ConcatTest()
    {
        Assert.IsNull(CustomConcat(null, null));
        Assert.AreEqual("one", CustomConcat("one", null));
        Assert.AreEqual("two", CustomConcat(null, "two"));
        Assert.AreEqual("onetwo", CustomConcat("one", "two"));

        // finally, a test for (a + b) ?? (c + d)
        Assert.AreEqual("threefour", CustomConcat(null, null) ?? CustomConcat("three", "four"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your actual formula is

```
(a + b) ?? (c + d) // assumes that null + null == null in (a + b)
```

I suggest rewriting it into

```
a == null && b == null ? c + d : a + b
```

which provides the expected result:

- if *both* `a` and `b` are `null` we have `c + d`
- `a + b` otherwise

If you want to have `null` (not empty string) when all `a, b, c, d` are `null`:

```
a == null && b == null ? 
  c == null && d == null 
    ? null 
    : c + d 
    : a + b;
```

Comment: Solving the XY problem, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, different method calls treat different preconditions, but you can always create your own function to handle "custom" preconditions.

As the most simple option you can try something like this:

```
String concatenateStrings(string s1, string s1) {
return (s1 == null && s2 == null)? null : String.concat(s1,s2);
}
```

Comment: Please read answers already added before posting an answer, and please avoid adding an answer that is very, very similar to other answers. BR – Roar S.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
            var textResult = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2))
            {
                textResult = null;
            }
            else
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2))
                {
                    textResult = text1;
                }
                else
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2))
                    {
                        textResult = text2;
                    }

            textResult = $"{text1} {text2}";
```

or in a better way:

```
        textResult = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2)) ?
            text1 :
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2)) ?
                        text2 :
                        (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1) && 
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text2)) ?
                        text2 :
                        $"{text1} {text2}";
```